# Updating state twice in a complex react logic

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So, I have a component like this which has quite complex logic in `updateCT` which I have simpler for the question

```
import { useState } from "react";
const App = () => {
  const setFinalPerson = (key,value) => {
    let updatedData = key
      ? {
          [key]: value
        }
      : value;
    setPerson((person) => ({
      ...person,
      ...updatedData
    }));
  };

  const updateCT = (key, value) => {
    const { info } = person;
    const newInfo = {
      ...info,
      [key]: value
    };
    setFinalPerson('info', newInfo);
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    updateCT("age", "23");
    updateCT("name", "Henry");
  };

  const [person, setPerson] = useState({
    info: {
      name: "Max",
      age: "22"
    },
    bank: {
      account: "22345333455",
      balance: "7000"
    }
  });
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{`Name ${person.info.name}`}</h1>
      <h1>{`Age ${person.info.age}`}</h1>
      <h1>{`Account Number ${person.bank.account}`}</h1>
      <h1>{`Balance ${person.bank.balance}`}</h1>

      <button onClick={onClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

So, when i click on the button, i want to change age and name of the person in info.
I know that first it is updating state for age, but when it updates state for name, it gets the older state with old value of age. Therefore, ultimately the age is not getting updated.

According to  [React Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates), I have to use functional way to update state, but the state object is too complex in real and I just cant use spread operators to that much nesting of object.

Is there any way, I can solve this problem?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, the code isn't effected in any way if you change the onclick to `onClick={() => onClick()}`. The only thing that changes is that the `setState` works accordingly. Can you provide more information why this doesn't work in your case?

Comment: So the problem is, if we want to use the latest state, we us something like `setPerson((person) => ());` . But , my state is so nested , I can put all the functional logic in that function. So, how can i access the latest state without using that  `setPerson((person) => ());`

Answer (score 0):

If your true state is actually much more complex than you are showing, a potential solution is the `useReducer` hook instead. But in this case I fail to see why you would need that, you are essentially wanting to update `name` and `age` on the `info` key at the same time?

> but the state object is too complex in real and I just cant use spread operators to that much nesting of object.

There's not really a limit to how much nesting you can have. Perhaps you can re-architect the data structure but it is pretty typical to use a good amount of Object spread to redefine state values. In conclusion you want all of your state changing to happen one time otherwise render will run when you change the state so you will re-overwrite it with the past info and you'll never get to change state twice.

Without seeing your true usecase I fail to see why `useReducer` would be necessary, but that's an option to consider and `useEffect` is also a possibility. You can set `useEffect` to change some state if that's dependent on a different state change. Such as: when the user's name changes, find their age:

```js
const nameByAgeLookup = {
john: 23,
jack: 41,
jill: 12
}

const [name, setName] = useState('')
const [age, setAge] = useState(Infinity)

useEffect(() => {
setAge(nameByAgeLookup[name])
}, [name])
```

```js
const { useState } = React;
const App = () => {
  const [person, setPerson] = useState({
    info: {
      name: "Max",
      age: "22"
    },
    bank: {
      account: "22345333455",
      balance: "7000"
    }
  });

  const setFinalPerson = (key,value) => {
    let updatedData = key
      ? {
          [key]: value
        }
      : value;
    setPerson((person) => ({
      ...person,
      ...updatedData
    }));
  };

  const updateCT = (newInfo) => {
    const { info } = person;
    const merged = {
      ...info,
      ...newInfo
    };
    setFinalPerson('info', merged);
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    updateCT({age: "23", name: "Henry" });
  };


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{`Name ${person.info.name}`}</h1>
      <h1>{`Age ${person.info.age}`}</h1>
      <h1>{`Account Number ${person.bank.account}`}</h1>
      <h1>{`Balance ${person.bank.balance}`}</h1>

      <button onClick={onClick}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
<App />,
window.root
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Yes, i want to update name, age and info at the same time

Comment: then in my solution I do that: allow updateCT to take in an object (which allows you to set as many keys and values at the same time) rather than a single key and a single value. It is likely/possible that you want a sort of draft state to keep track of these and maybe on some other event like onSubmit/onBlur/onScroll actually make a post. In most cases the user changes a name input and then an age input not both at the same time.